# Chaining Promises in Office.js with Excel.run()

Tags: excel, ms-office, office365, office-js

I’m working with the new office.js. I’m using the Excel.run functionality that returns a promise. I have a question about the promises pattern implemented by the library.

The samples all show this pattern

```js
Excel.run( function (ctx) {

  //set up something

  return ctx.sync().then (function () {
    //call another function somewhere to chain operations
  });

}).then ( function () {
  //do something else if you want
}).catch (function (error) {
  handle errors
});
```

The problem is the ctx.sync().then() contained within Excel.run()
The way it is presented, you can’t chain promises in accordance with the promises spec because you lose the context object if you try and handle the then() outside of Excel.run()
So, the pattern seems to be promoting nested function calls, which is what promises are supposed to eliminate.

What I want to do is sequence several calls together through chaining like this:

```js
Excel.run( function (ctx) {
  return ctx.sync();
}).then ( function (ctx) {
  return ctx.sync();
}).then ( function (ctx) {
  return ctx.sync();
}).then ( function (ctx) {
  return ctx.sync();
}).catch (function (error) {

});
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11):

In general, the purpose of `Excel.run` is for a sequential operation against the OM with automatic cleanup at the end. That is, `Excel.run` creates a context, runs you operation, and then cleans up any host objects that were allocated.

That being said, as mentioned by Gab Royer, you *can* pass objects out. And moreover, each Excel object has a back-pointer to its "context" via the ".context" property. So for example, you can do this:

```js
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var worksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    return ctx.sync(worksheet);
}).then(function(worksheet) {
    worksheet.name = "Test"
    return worksheet.context.sync();
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e)  
});
```

As you can see, in the code above, you had created the worksheet object inside the `Excel.run`, but are using it outside.

If you have something like a Range object, it gets a little trickier.  Ranges, unlike Worksheets, do *not* have persistent IDs (How could they? There is essentially a countless number of permutations of all possible combinations of cells). Instead, during `Excel.run`, we automatically create persistent pointers to the backing Range objects that get adjusted and kept-track-of by Excel. When the batch inside of `Excel.run` completes, we tell the host to destroy these references. So if you had code like this:

```js
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var range = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
    return ctx.sync(range);
}).then(function(range) {
    range.format.fill.color = "red";
    return ctx.sync();
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e)  
})
```

It would run into an "InvalidObjectPath" error.

However, you can opt out of the tracked-object cleanup by manually adding the object to the `ctx.trackedObjects` collection.  In doing this, however, you are taking it upon yourself to clean up at the end -- and you need to be extra careful, to remember to cleanup on not only on success, but on failure.  Otherwise, you're essentially creating a memory leak that will keep slowing down the Excel host application.

```js
var range;
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    range = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
    ctx.trackedObjects.add(range);
    return ctx.sync(range);
}).then(function(range) {
    range.format.fill.color = "red";
    return range.context.sync();
}).then(function() {
    // Attempt to clean up any orphaned references
    range.context.trackedObjects.remove(range);
    range.context.sync(); // don't need to await it, since it's just the final cleanup call
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
})
```

Long story short:  it is certainly doable, and you can use objects after `Excel.run`.  You'll just need to be responsible for memory-management for any objects that require "tracking".  In the example above, there is no *reason* to go through this effort, since you could just as well have had the same code inside of Excel.run (remember, you can chain promises *within* the batch inside of Excel.run, too -- no need to do this on the outside). But if you have a scenario, where, say, you have a timer job that needs to run every so often (e.g., to update a stock ticker), or you want to create a button with an onclick handler for a particular object, etc. the technique above will let you create the objects inside of Excel.run, and then use them outside of it.

**PS**: With regards to the pattern requiring nesting: It is true that if you need to chain `ctx.sync()` calls within Excel.run, you will end up with a layer of nesting -- but just a *single* extra layer. Within, you still would still be able to chain your promises without the callback pyramid. E.g.,:

```js
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var range = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().getRange("A1:C3");
    range.load("values");
    return ctx.sync()
        .then(function () {
            // Some set of actions against the OM, now that the "values"
            // property has been loaded and can be read from the "range" object.
        })
        .then(ctx.sync)
        .then(function () {
            // Another set of actions against the OM, presumably after doing
            // another load-requiring operation (otherwise could have
            // been part of the same .then as above)
        })
        .then(ctx.sync)
        .then(function() {
            // One final set of actions
        });     
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
});
```

Comment: This should be copied right into the documentation. Excellent insight. Thanks!

Comment: So you mentioned this : "you want to create a button with an onclick handler for a particular object, etc. the technique above will let you create the objects inside of Excel.run, and then use them outside of it."

I'm doing this very thing, but I'm finding that if I call `.select()` on my object body, my object is *not* scrolled to or highlighted, but I don't receive any exceptions.

I have a Word document with a table in it. I add a reference to a specific cell, add it as a tracked object, and attach an event handler. But nothing happens on click.

Has this worked for you?

Comment: To anyone who had this problem, I was misunderstanding the nature of context-syncing. Outside of my initial context, I had to open a new `Word.run` to get a new context, and then call `context.sync()` on my actual `trackedObject` after performing my `select()`. I think that is illustrated in the `setTimeOut` example fairly well, I just missed it.

Answer (score 1):

While this would be possible since `Excel.RequestContext.sync` takes in a pass-through value, the goal of `Excel.run` is to manage trackedObjects for the function that it gets passed in. In promises chained after `Excel.Run` you would have to manage trackedObjects yourself, hence defeating the purpose of Excel.Run.

I'd suggest either declaring your function outside the `Excel.Run` if you don't like the added indentation, or creating your own `RequestContext` object.